# Issue with Node maze navigation c++

Tags: c++, stack, maze

I have created a "maze" of Nodes with class Node defined by:

```
class Node
{
   public:
      Node(string newName);
      Node();
      void setNodeName(string newName);
      string getNodeName();
      void attachNewNode(Node *newNode, int direction);
      Node *getAttachedNode(int direction);
   private:
      string name;
      Node *attachedNodes[4];
};

Node::Node(string newName)
{
   name = newName;
}

Node::Node()
{};

void Node::setNodeName(string newName)
{
   name = newName;
}

string Node::getNodeName()
{
   return name;
}

void Node::attachNewNode(Node *newNode, int direction)
{
   attachedNodes[direction] = newNode;
}

Node* Node::getAttachedNode(int direction)
{
   return attachedNodes[direction];
}
```

I read in a file in the format:

```
9
A1
C3
A1 A2 B1 * *
A2 * B2 A1 *
A3 * B3 * *
B1 * * * A1
B2 B3 C2 * A2
B3 * * B2 A3
C1 C2 * * *
C2 C3 * C1 B2
C3 * * C2 *
```

Where 9 is the number of nodes to be created, A1 is the node we will begin navigation from, C3 is the node we will try to find a path to, and the following lines represent the nodes themselves and the pointers they have associated with them. For example:

```
A1 A2 B1 * *
```

represents node A1 has pointers to node A2 in the north, B1 in the east, null in the south, and null in the west.

```
A2 * B2 A1 *
```

represents node A2 has pointers to node null in the north, B2 in the east, A1 in the south, and null in the west.

I have a function that builds the "maze" of nodes stored in a map where the string key is the name of the Node itself. I am running a depth first search on the map in an attempt to find my way from the starting node (as specified in the file) to the ending node (also specified in the file).

I am running into trouble with how to access pieces of the map. Specifically, when I try as may DFS code:

```
string getPath()
{
   string path;
   vector<string> attachedNodes;
   stack<string> pathNodes;
   pathNodes.push(startNode.getNodeName());

   while(!pathNodes.empty())
   {
      string temp = pathNodes.top();
      path += temp + " ";

      cout << "Printing Temp." << endl;
      cout << "Temp is: " << temp << " in this case." << endl;

      if(temp == endNode.getNodeName())
         return path;

      for(map<string,Node>::iterator it = rooms.begin(); it != rooms.end(); it++)
      {
         if(it->second.getNodeName() == temp)
         {
            attachedNodes.push_back(rooms[temp].getAttachedNode(1)->getNodeName());
            attachedNodes.push_back(rooms[temp].getAttachedNode(2)->getNodeName());
            attachedNodes.push_back(rooms[temp].getAttachedNode(3)->getNodeName());
            attachedNodes.push_back(rooms[temp].getAttachedNode(4)->getNodeName());
         }
      }

      pathNodes.pop();

      for(int i = 0; i < attachedNodes.size(); i++)
         pathNodes.push(attachedNodes[i]);
   }

   return path;
}
```

However, I am running into issues all over the place. If I compile and run the above code, I am presented with the following output:

```
"Printing Temp."
" in this case."
```

Notice the white space in front of "in this case" and the lack of the temp variable. If I add .substr(0,2) to the temp assignment in getPath(), I am presented with an infinite loop! Something must be wrong with how I am accessing the top() of the stack of strings, right? Help!

Edit: Code from the main method includes:

```
main()
{
    string file = getFileName(); //reads the file name from user input
    buildGraph(file); //builds the map

    cout << endl << "The nodes in the current map are:" << endl;
    for(map<string,Node>::iterator it = rooms.begin(); it != rooms.end(); it++)
    {
       cout << "current node: " << it->second.getNodeName() << endl;
       if(it->second.getAttachedNode(1)->getNodeName().length() < 3)
          cout << it->second.getAttachedNode(1)->getNodeName() << endl;
       if(it->second.getAttachedNode(2)->getNodeName().length() < 3)
          cout << it->second.getAttachedNode(2)->getNodeName() << endl;
       if(it->second.getAttachedNode(3)->getNodeName().length() < 3)
          cout << it->second.getAttachedNode(3)->getNodeName() << endl;
       if(it->second.getAttachedNode(4)->getNodeName().length() <  3)
          cout << it->second.getAttachedNode(4)->getNodeName() << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Exited for in main." << endl << endl;

    string path = getPath();
}
```

Comment: strange on the debug output - almost like there is a carriage return character causing to overwrite - is that a possibility?

Comment: @wwkudu I am not sure. The only code I didn't include was code from the main method that read data from file and called functions that built the "maze". I will edit the post above to reflect this concern.

Comment: I may be blind but I don't see where you define startNode which is what getPath uses to get going. Is BuildGraph working correctly?

Comment: Build graph provides a map<string,Node> rooms full of nodes with string key that is also its name. startNode and endNode are defined in the buildGraph() function that I am confident works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
attachedNodes.push_back(rooms[temp].getAttachedNode(1)->getNodeName());
```

if `getAttachedNode(1)` returns NULL, then will be trying to call `getNodeName()` on a NULL object. This is bad.

You need to check for NULL first, something like this would do

```
if (rooms[temp].getAttachedNode(1) != NULL)
    attachedNodes.push_back(rooms[temp].getAttachedNode(1)->getNodeName());
```

But I am not even sure why you are doing this. You are looping around `room` trying to find the current room, then when you do find it, you use the map to locate it directly anyway.

You also never clear out your local `attachedNodes` variable, so it will keep getting bigger and bigger. You don't need the `attachedNodes` local variable, as you can just use the room's attachedNodes list instead.

Assuming attachedNodes always point to valid rooms (or NULL), you can replace the two loops with:

```
  pathNodes.pop();

  for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
     if (rooms[temp].getAttachedNode(i) != NULL) 
        pathNodes.push(rooms[temp].getAttachedNode(i));
  }
```

This should get you a bit further, but you need to look at your algorithm as well, all you are currently doing is pushing all available attached nodes onto the path.